# Unable to use Body Parser to access input value

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

I am unable to parse the Value filled in input using Body Parser. Here is my the code i am using. any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the compose Page in ejs

```html
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>
<form class="form" action="/compose" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><h4 class="display-6">Blog Title</h4></label>
    <input name = "postTitle" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter Title"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h4 class="display-6">Enter Blog </h4></label>
    <textarea
      class="form-control"
      id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
      rows="3"
      name="blogtext"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success mt-4" name="button">Publish Blog</button>
</form>

<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

Here is my express server

```js
// const { log } = require("console");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.get("/",(req,res) =>{
    res.render("mainpage")
})
app.get("/compose",(req,res) =>{
    res.render("compose")
})
app.post("/compose",(res,req)=>{
    console.log(req.body.postTitle);
})
app.listen('3000',()=> console.log('server started'));
```

I want to get both 'postTitle' and 'blogtext' to get saved and then i can render it on page. Kindly suggest what wrong i am doing. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think newer versions of Express are bundled with `bodyParser`. Which version of Express are you running?

Comment: "Kindly suggest what wrong i am doing" — Well, ```app.post("/compose",(res,req)=>{
    console.log(req.body.postTitle);
})``` will log `postTitle` and do nothing else. It won't save it. It won't make a response (so the browser's request will time out). Please read [ask]. What behaviour do you see when you run this code? How is this different from the behaviour you expect?

Comment: Hi @Quentin "Well, app.post("/compose",(res,req)=>{     console.log(req.body.postTitle); }) will log postTitle and do nothing else" it is not able to log the vale and shows this error = " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postTitle')". I have used the lines in my code = "app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));" but nothing still works

Comment: You made a typo `res,req` are backwards. The request is the **first** argument, the response is the **second** argument. (And you only made it on that one route!)

Comment: Oh my god, Thanks for pointing out my friend @Quentin ... I begin seriously doubting my coding abilities (not that vast, i am still a beginner). Much appreciated